# factor conversion using dynamic names

Tags: r, dplyr, categorical-data

I currently access the "v" column of the "two" data frame dynamically and I'd like to turn it into a factor with levels from the "one" data frame. I am currently getting NAs when I use factor() on two[,variable] . Any idea how to get this to work?

```
one =data.frame(v=c("B","A"))
two = data.frame(v=c("A","B"))
variable = "v"
two[,variable] = factor(two[,variable] ,levels = one$v, ordered = TRUE)

   v
1 <NA>
2 <NA>
```

Comment: Have you looked through previous posts like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/dynamically-select-data-frame-columns-using-and-a-vector-of-column-names and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el?noredirect=1&lq=1? It looks like you're having trouble with how to get access to a column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, 'one' is also a data.frame, so we need to extract the corresponding column from 'one'

```
two[, variable] <- factor(two[,variable] ,levels = one[, variable], ordered = TRUE)
two[, variable]
#[1] A B
#Levels: B < A
```

If it is a `tibble`, the `two[, variable]` would still be a `tibble` with one column.  To extract column as a vector (as `factor` method work on `vector`) either we use `$` or `[[`

```
two[[variable]] <- factor(two[[variable]], levels = one[[variable]], ordered = TRUE)
```

Which would also work in `base R`

---

NOTE: The OP first showed an example where `levels = one`.  Now, it is changed to `one$v`.  which would work if it is run again after creating the 'two' data.frame

Comment: well I think it had something to do with tibble vs. data frame but thank you

Comment: @user3022875  But, your example is `data.frame`.  If it is a tibble you need `two[[variable]]` and `one[[variable]]` which would work in both tibble and data.frame

Comment: my mistake I didn't see that it was a tibble. thanks